# Menu JavaScript GetId

Tags: javascript, css, javascript-eventos

Tenho um menu que possui um efeito 'hoverline' ("uma linha que corre para baixo do elemento clicado!") com JavaScript, porém ele é criado usando o getId puxando o ID dos elementos.

O desafio é duplicar o menu mantendo o efeito 'hoverline' nos dois, estou quebrando a cabeça de como posso manter o efeito em dois menus, não sei se a melhor forma é buscar uma maneira sem usar o getId ou se existe como duplicar o mesmo mantendo os ID dos elementos.

Código:

```js
var SETTINGS = {
    navBarTravelling: false,
    navBarTravelDirection: "",
  navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
    0: "#867100",
    1: "#7F4200",
    2: "#99813D",
    3: "#40FEFF",
    4: "#14CC99",
    5: "#00BAFF",
    6: "#0082B2",
    7: "#B25D7A",
    8: "#00FF17",
    9: "#006B49",
    10: "#00B27A",
    11: "#996B3D",
    12: "#CC7014",
    13: "#40FF8C",
    14: "#FF3400",
    15: "#ECBB5E",
    16: "#ECBB0C",
    17: "#B9D912",
    18: "#253A93",
    19: "#125FB9",
}


document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// the indicator
var indicador = document.getElementById("indicador");

var trilho = document.getElementById("trilho");

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(trilho.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link"));
 links.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
 })
 e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
 // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
 moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});


// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
    var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    var container = trilhoContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var distance = textPosition.left - container;
  var scroll = trilhoContents.scrollLeft;
    indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
 // count = count += 100;
 // indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";
 
    if (color) {
        indicador.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
    var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
    var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
    var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
    var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
    var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
  if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
        return "both";
    } else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
        return "left";
    } else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
        return "right";
    } else {
        return "none";
    }
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.menu_horizontal {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 11px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.trilho_classe {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.trilho_classe_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.trilho_classe_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_horizontal">
<nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">
    <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="true">Chairs</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Tables</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Cookware</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Beds</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Desks</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Flooring</a>
 <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator"></span>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: **Arthur**, *Java* e *JavaScript* são linguagens de programação totalmente distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer criar outro menu para outras funcionalidades acredito que a melhor forma é usando o getId, todavia você terá que colocar ids únicos para renderizar.
 Até da pra criar funções com parâmetros, mas aí entra uma questão de *tempo x resultado*.

```js
var SETTINGS = {
    navBarTravelling: false,
    navBarTravelDirection: "",
  navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
    0: "#867100",
    1: "#7F4200",
    2: "#99813D",
    3: "#40FEFF",
    4: "#14CC99",
    5: "#00BAFF",
    6: "#0082B2",
    7: "#B25D7A",
    8: "#00FF17",
    9: "#006B49",
    10: "#00B27A",
    11: "#996B3D",
    12: "#CC7014",
    13: "#40FF8C",
    14: "#FF3400",
    15: "#ECBB5E",
    16: "#ECBB0C",
    17: "#B9D912",
    18: "#253A93",
    19: "#125FB9",
}


document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// the indicator
var indicador = document.getElementById("indicador");

var trilho = document.getElementById("trilho");

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(trilho.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link"));
 links.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
 })
 e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
 // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
 moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});


// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
    var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    var container = trilhoContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var distance = textPosition.left - container;
  var scroll = trilhoContents.scrollLeft;
    indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
 // count = count += 100;
 // indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";
 
    if (color) {
        indicador.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
    var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
    var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
    var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
    var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
    var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
  if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
        return "both";
    } else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
        return "left";
    } else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
        return "right";
    } else {
        return "none";
    }
}

var indicador2 = document.getElementById("indicador2");
var trilho2 = document.getElementById("trilho2");

var colours2 = {
    0: "#867100",
    1: "#7F4200",
    2: "#99813D",
    3: "#40FEFF",
    4: "#14CC99",
    5: "#00BAFF",
    6: "#0082B2",
    7: "#B25D7A",
    8: "#00FF17",
    9: "#006B49",
    10: "#00B27A",
    11: "#996B3D",
    12: "#CC7014",
    13: "#40FF8C",
    14: "#FF3400",
    15: "#ECBB5E",
    16: "#ECBB0C",
    17: "#B9D912",
    18: "#253A93",
    19: "#125FB9",
}

// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator2(item, color) {
    var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
    var container = trilhoContents2.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var distance = textPosition.left - container;
  var scroll = trilhoContents2.scrollLeft;
    indicador2.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
 // count = count += 100;
 // indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";
 
    if (color) {
        indicador2.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator2(trilho2.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours2[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents2.addEventListener("click", function(f) {
 var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link2"));
 links.forEach(function(item) {
  item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
 })
 f.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
 // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
 moveIndicator2(f.target, colours2[links.indexOf(f.target)]);
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

.menu_horizontal {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 11px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.trilho_classe {
    /* Make this scrollable when needed */
    overflow-x: auto;
    /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
    .js & {
        /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        &::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    }
 /* positioning context for advancers */
 position: relative;
 /*Crush the whitespace here*/
 font-size: 0;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents {
 float: left;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 position: relative;
}

.trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
 transition: none;
}

.trilho_classe_Link {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}

.trilho_classe_Indicator {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 4px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: transparent;
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.trilho_classe_Link2 {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888;
 /*Reset the font size*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 11px;
 & + & {
  border-left-color: #eee;
 }
 &[aria-selected="true"] {
  color: #111;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_horizontal">
<nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">
    <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link" aria-selected="true">Chairs</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Tables</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Cookware</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Beds</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Desks</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link">Flooring</a>
 <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator"></span>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="menu_horizontal">
<nav id="trilho2" class="trilho_classe">
    <div id="trilhoContents2" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2" aria-selected="true">Chairs</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2">Tables</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2">Cookware</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2">Beds</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2">Desks</a>
        <a href="#" class="trilho_classe_Link2">Flooring</a>
 <span id="indicador2" class="trilho_classe_Indicator"></span>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pelo seu tempo, me ajudou muito!